# Prove an implication with probability

Tags: probability

I have a discrete random variable $X:\Omega\to A$, where $A\subset\Bbb R$ and indexed by $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, such that $a_i\in A$. I would like to prove the following statement $\forall p,q,r,s\in\{1\dots,n\}$ and for some $b,c\in A$:

$$P(a_p>X>b)-P(a_q>X>b)>P(a_s>X>c)-P(a_t>X>c)\Rightarrow a_p-a_q>a_s-a_t $$

I need to determine what additional assumptions I can impose on the probability distribution in order for this to be true, and then how to prove that it is true.

First attempt: I am guessing I need something to do with monotonicity and/or linearity, but I do not know how to formalize this.

Are there any straightforward assumptions that I can impose in order to make this statement true?

Comment: Probability of what?  How many random variables do you have here?  Are $x,x',y,s,s',t$ all random variables?  Might they be dependent in some way?  But if they are random variables, what does $x'-x>s'-s$ mean?

Comment: But then what does $x'-x>s'-s$ mean?  Do you mean that the random variable on the left is *always* greater than the variable on the right (well, probability $1$, that is)?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Don't leave critical information for the comments.  Also, please add some context.  Why is this condition of interest?  Have you encountered a collection of random variables for which your claim holds?

Comment: I've implemented the requested edits. Please let me know if anything remains unclear.

Comment: This isn't clear at all...I have no idea what the $x_i$ etc. are, for example.  I think you are trying to extract this question from some particular context, and maybe it makes sense in that context, but it really doesn't make sense without it.

Comment: More to the point, if $x,x',\cdots$ are *known* random variables then the desired condition, whatever it means, is either known to be true or it is known to be false.  So maybe you meant to say something like "if the premise holds for a suitably broad class of variables $y,t$ then the conclusion holds".  But I am just guessing here, and I have no guess as to what "suitably broad" might mean here.

Comment: I made some additional edits to hopefully clarify the context a bit more. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something more fundamental about the way probability distributions work, but in any case an explanation as to what I might be misunderstanding would be helpful too.

Comment: a random variable is define as $X:\Omega\to S$ where $\Omega$ is your sample set, and $S$ is your set of numbers. For making sense of what you are asking, you are using just one random variable.

Comment: I see that you accepted the edition. Now you need yo give certain relation between the indeces $p$, $q$, $s$, $t$  and also the elements $b$ and $c$. Note that is $X$ takes value only in the $\Bbb N_0$, then you can drop the indeces and define directo relation between the elements.